# How to avoid of touching text at the edge of 'overflow hidden' div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have applied dynamic height of an element which is the part of an `overflow: hidden` div. The problem is, though I have applied `overflow: hidden` and `padding-bottom: 20px;` to the element, text of the element touch the edge of it's parent. How to avoid that?

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 190px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.box p {
  padding: 10px 10px 20px;
  margin: 0;
}
.des {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p class="title">Title of post Title of post Title of post Title of post Title of post Title of post Title of post Title of post</p>
  <div class="des">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin nisi ligula, dapibus a volutpat sit amet, mattis et dui. Nunc porttitor accumsan orci id luctus. Phasellus ipsum metus, tincidunt non rhoncus id, dictum a lectus. Nam sed ipsum a lacus
      sodales eleifend. Vestibulum lorem felis, rhoncus elementum vestibulum eget, dictum ut velit. Nullam venenatis, elit in suscipit imperdiet, orci purus posuere mauris, quis adipiscing ipsum urna ac quam.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place another div (let's say `.box-inner`) at the bottom of the `.box` element that will hide the text behind it.

Just give the .box a position:relative and give a position absolute to the `.box-inner` div.

**NOTE:** Give the `.box-inner` a background color same as the text's background

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 190px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Add relative position */
  position:relative;
}
.box p {
  padding: 10px 10px 20px;
  margin: 0;
}
.des {
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Newly added element */
.box-inner {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   height:10px;
   background-color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p class="title">Title of post Title of post Title of post Title of post Title of post Title of post Title of post Title of post</p>
  <div class="des">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin nisi ligula, dapibus a volutpat sit amet, mattis et dui. Nunc porttitor accumsan orci id luctus. Phasellus ipsum metus, tincidunt non rhoncus id, dictum a lectus. Nam sed ipsum a lacus
      sodales eleifend. Vestibulum lorem felis, rhoncus elementum vestibulum eget, dictum ut velit. Nullam venenatis, elit in suscipit imperdiet, orci purus posuere mauris, quis adipiscing ipsum urna ac quam.</p>
  </div>
<div class="box-inner"></div>
</div>
```

---

**SOLUTION #2 (Box inside box)**

Add `.box-inner` as child element of `.box` and put all content in it. Do not give any border.

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 190px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Add relative position */
  position:relative;
}
.box p {
  padding: 0 0 10px;
  margin: 0;
}
.des {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box-inner {
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
  right:10px;
  bottom:10px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-inner">
  <p class="title">Title of post Title of post Title of post Title of post Title of post Title of post Title of post Title of post</p>
  <div class="des">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin nisi ligula, dapibus a volutpat sit amet, mattis et dui. Nunc porttitor accumsan orci id luctus. Phasellus ipsum metus, tincidunt non rhoncus id, dictum a lectus. Nam sed ipsum a lacus
      sodales eleifend. Vestibulum lorem felis, rhoncus elementum vestibulum eget, dictum ut velit. Nullam venenatis, elit in suscipit imperdiet, orci purus posuere mauris, quis adipiscing ipsum urna ac quam.</p>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Basically, the real scenario of my issue is something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/k5VET/3116/
There are transparent background-color at the main box. That's why, adding another fake element by HTML/CSS is clearly visible.

Answer (score 1):

According to me a better way to achieve this is to use `:after` pseudo selector. This will display a white strip at the end of the box with given hide. Thus hides the bottom line which touches the bottom border and gives look of the padding.

Here is the code:

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 190px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.box p {
  padding: 10px 10px 20px;
  margin: 0;
}
.des {
  padding: 10px 10px 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box:after{
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p class="title">Title of post Title of post Title of post Title of post Title of post Title of post Title of post Title of post</p>
  <div class="des">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin nisi ligula, dapibus a volutpat sit amet, mattis et dui. Nunc porttitor accumsan orci id luctus. Phasellus ipsum metus, tincidunt non rhoncus id, dictum a lectus. Nam sed ipsum a lacus
      sodales eleifend. Vestibulum lorem felis, rhoncus elementum vestibulum eget, dictum ut velit. Nullam venenatis, elit in suscipit imperdiet, orci purus posuere mauris, quis adipiscing ipsum urna ac quam.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Basically, the real scenario of my issue is something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/k5VET/3116/
There are transparent background-color at the main box. That's why, adding another fake element by HTML/CSS is clearly visible.